# Angular SignalR disconnected after receive first data

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I have app some like chat. Backend of course in .net core and frontend in Angular. My problem rely on that after receive first message to chat, SignalR connection is disconnected automatically. I overrride OnDisconnectedAsync method in backend but exception object, i received there, is null. The same situation on onclose method in angular with error object. I get the following information in browser log:

```
[2021-01-27T18:05:34.398Z] Information: Connection disconnected. Utils.js:209
```

Interesting is, this first message is succesfully provided to angular app and showing at the webpage.
I tried to use

```
Object.defineProperty(WebSocket, 'OPEN', {value: 1});
```

But the same situation occur.
My angular code:

```
    startConnection() {

    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()

     .withUrl('http://localhost.:80/' + 'chats')
     .build();

    this.hubConnection
     .start()
     .then(() => this.hubConnection.invoke<boolean>('RegisterConnection').then(value => {
      if (!value.valueOf()) {
          throw new Error('HUBMESSAGE: error returned from web api.');
        }
      }))
     .catch(err => console.log('HUBMESSAGE: Error while starting connection: ' + err));

     this.hubConnection
     .onclose(error => {
        console.log('HUBMESSAGE: err occur: ' + error);
        console.log('State: ' + this.hubConnection.state);
     });
   }

   getData(): Observable<MessageStatus> {
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }

  changeChatId(chatId: number) {
    this.hubConnection.invoke<boolean>('AssingToChat', chatId).then(value => {
      if (!value.valueOf()) {
          throw new Error('HUBMESSAGE: error returned from web api.');
        }
      })
     .catch(err => console.log('HUBMESSAGE: Error while starting connection: ' + err));
  }

   addTransferChartDataListener() {
     console.log('HUBMESSAGE: listen');
     this.hubConnection.on('chatchartdata', (data) => {
       console.log('Received hub chat data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
       const streamStatus: MessageStatus = { senderName: data[0], content: data[1], sentTime: data[3] }
       this.data.next(streamStatus);
     });
   }
```

There are some additional calls to specife clients to who messages should be provided. So on the backend side, is some classes to handle this logic. Finally the most close to this issue is following method which is used to send data:

```
private async Task ExecuteRequest(Message message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Activiy of hub");

        object[] messageArgs = { message.SenderName, message.Content, message.GetFormattedSentTime() };

        string[] connectionIds = _hubManager.GetAllConnectionAssignedToSpecificChat(message.ChatId);
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        Console.WriteLine($"Try to send message {message.Content}");

        foreach(string connectionId in connectionIds)
        {
            tasks.Add(_hub.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync(METHOD, messageArgs, cancellationToken: _token).ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Fault during executing task: {task.Exception?.Message ?? "exception"}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {message.Content} was sent to {connectionId}");
                }
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

For any help many thanks!
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution! Cancellation token in SendAsync method of Hub was causing disconnection. What a absurd!